# EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read in React Native file system

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-fs

I'm trying simple code to copy a file to another external folder using this code:

```
RNFS.copyFile(sourcePath, destinationPath)
.then(result => {
  console.log('file copied:', result);
})
.catch(err => {
  console.log('error: ', err.message, err.code);
});
```

and i have already granted `Android.Permission` for read and write in external directory but it's still returning this error:

```
error:  EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read '/storage/emulated/0/' EISDIR
```

here are the dependency:

```
"react": "16.9.0",
"react-native": "0.61.2",
"react-native-fs": "^2.15.2"
```

BTW Am i request correct permission ?

```
PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE 
PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

Thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have resolved this issue, It was silly mistake. I forgot to mention name of the file in destination path url:

```
let sourcePath = "/storage/emulated/0/SourceFolder";
let destinationPath = "/storage/emulated/0/DestinationFolder";
let FileName = 'abc.jpg';

destinationPath = destinationPath +"/"+ FileName;

  RNFS.copyFile(sourcePath, destinationPath)  
    .then(result => {  
      console.log('file copied:', result);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it works for me.

```
import {view, StyleSheet, PermissionsAndroid} from from 'react-native';

PermissionsAndroid.request(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    PermissionsAndroid.request(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
```

Comment: Permissions were already taken as mentioned by OP. Moreover, this porblem was solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58554057/14291243